# Controlling the speed of a value?

Tags: animation, drivers

I need to animate a rotor, so rather than keyframing the Z rotation it would be easier to animate its rotation speed. I saw examples with a driver where a spin value is multiplied by the current frame, but it can't be animated because the rotor just rewinds if the spin is animated back to zero. Is there a way to animate the speed, use physics or make a simple PID setup in a driver?

Comment: Constant speed would be easy to do with extrapolation, I want to animate it starting up then shutting down.